# drop list con conexión a base de datos

Tags: angular, typescript

tengo un problema con mi proyecto de angular, quiero realizar un drop list en el que me muestre todas las opciones que me da un campo de una tabla de mi base de datos, pero no se como aplicarlo, para explicarme mejor, añado imagen de referencia de lo que quiero hacer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el detalle es que lo que quiero realizar es un implemento de este drop list pero dinámico, que me salga los datos que están dentro de un campo en una tabla (conexión a la base y y api ya hechas)
según viendo los códigos se hace de esta manera:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'app-dropdown-sample-1',
    styleUrls: ['./dropdown-sample-1.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './dropdown-sample-1.component.html'
})
export class DropDownSample1Component {
    public items: { field: string }[] = [
        { field: 'Option 1' },
        { field: 'Option 2' },
        { field: 'Option 3' }
    ];
}
```

```css
.button {
    margin: 8px;
    width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" igxButton="raised" [igxToggleAction]="dropdown"
    [igxDropDownItemNavigation]="dropdown">Options</button>
<igx-drop-down #dropdown>
    <igx-drop-down-item *ngFor="let item of items">
        {{ item.field }}
    </igx-drop-down-item>
</igx-drop-down>
```

como dije antes, no se como podría aplicar este codigo a lo que busco o si hay una manera mas fácil
(comparto código de como está estructurado hasta el momento sin agregar el método)

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Modelo } from '../models/modelo.model';

import {ApiDataService} from './../services/api-data.service';



import { DocumentDefinition, PdfMakeWrapper, Table } from 'pdfmake-wrapper';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import { muestreomodel } from '../models/muestreo.model';





PdfMakeWrapper.setFonts(pdfFonts);

const pdf = new PdfMakeWrapper();


@Component({
  selector: 'app-empleado',
  templateUrl: './empleado.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./empleado.component.css']
})
export class EmpleadoComponent implements OnInit {

 
 

  //IMPORTA EL MODELO PARA IMPORTAR EL LOS CAMPOS QUE SE UTILIZARÁN 

  modelo = new Modelo();

  //DEFINIENDO ELEMENTOS PARA INGRESAR Y LEER DATOS

  public allPersons : any;

  private data: any;

  public allAfp : any;

  public Muestreoall: any;


  /*Muestreo(){

    return this._api.Muestreo().subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;


      this.Muestreoall = this.data.afp2;
    
      
    })


  }
*/
  //IMPORTACIÓN DE LA API PARA UTILIZAR LA CONEXIÓN DEL BACKEND AL FRONTEND

  constructor( private _api: ApiDataService) { }

  ngOnInit()  {

// MUESTRA LOS DATOS EN PANTALLA


    return this._api.MuestraAFP().subscribe((data)=>{
 
      this.data = data;
      this.allAfp = this.data.afps;

   
    

    });
    
  }

  

  // FUNCIÓN QUE PERMITE INGRESAR DATOS
ingresoEmpleados(){
  return this._api.getInsertEmpleados(this.modelo).subscribe((data:any)=>{
    // CONDICIONAL POR SI LOS DATOS INGRESADOS SON SIMILARES AL CODIGO DE IDENTIFICACIÓN
    
      //SI LA SENTENCIA NO ES CIERTA, PROCEDERÁ A INGRESAR LA INFORMACIÓN A LA BASE
      this.allAfp = [...this.allAfp, {...this.modelo}].sort((a,  b) => a.COD_CIA - b.COD_CIA);
    
  })
}
// FUNCIÓN QUE PERMITE ACTUALIZAR DATOS
ActualizarEmpleados(){
  /*POR MEDIO DE ESTA SENTENCIA DE CODIGO LE DIGO A MI PROGRAMA QUE CUANDO MANDE LA ACTUALIZACIÓN POR MEDIO DEL BOTÓN "EDITAR" SE HAGA
  UN EVENTO QUE LOGRE CONECTAR CON LA BASE Y ACTUALICE LOS DATOS POR MEDIO DEL ID QUE SERÁ EL IDENTIFICADOR PARA SABER QUE DATOS SE ACTUALIZARÁN*/
  return this._api.putUpdateEmpleados(this.modelo).subscribe((data:any)=>{
    this.allAfp = [...this.allAfp].map((item) => {
      if (item.COD_CIA == data.data.COD_CIA) {
        return data.data;
      }
      return item;
    })
  })
}




/* FUNCIÓN QUE ME PERMITE POR MEDIO DE UN EVENTO LLAMADO "(click)="EliminarEmpleado(p.COD_CIA)" DE PARTE DEL HTML
MANDAR UNA PETICIÓN AUTOMÁTICA PARA ELIMINAR LOS DATOS SIN NECESIDAD DE LLENAR UN FORMULARIO
*/
EliminarEmpleado(COD_CIA: any){
  return this._api.DeleteEmpleados(COD_CIA).subscribe((data:any)=>{
  
    this.allAfp = [...this.allAfp].filter(
      (item) => item.COD_CIA != data.data.COD_CIA
    );
  })
  


 }

 //por medio de un evento "(click)" proveniente del html, logro capturar los datos y mostrarlos en pdf
 Generarpdf(empleado:any){

  

//constante que me permite generar el esquema de la tabla con la información de la base
const tabla =  new Table([
    ['COD_CIA', 'Primer nombre', 'Segundo Nombre', 'Primer Apellido', 'Segundo Apellido'],
    [empleado.COD_CIA, empleado.PRIMER_NOMBRE, empleado.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE, empleado.PRIMER_APELLIDO, empleado.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO],
   
]).end;

//inicializador del pdf
 const pdf = new PdfMakeWrapper();
 pdf.add( tabla);


 pdf.create().open();

 pdf.create().download();

//pdfMake.createPdf(tabla).download();

 console.log(pdf)

 console.log(empleado);

 return empleado;




 



   
 
}
}
```

```css
.titulo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<h1>EMPLEADOS</h1>
<hr>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row  ">
        <div class="col ">
            <!--BOTÓN PARA ABRIR UN MODAL Y POR MEDIO DE ESE MODAL, INGRESAR LA INFORMACIÓN QUE SE SOLICITA PARA INGRESARLA A LA BASE DE DATOS-->
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"> Agregar</i>
  </button>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ingresa Los datos </h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <!--FORM-->
                            <!--LA ETIQUETA FORM Y LA FUNCIÓN "(ngSubmit)="ingresoEmpleados()"" ME PERMITEN PODER ENVIAR LOS DATOS A LA FUNCION DE MI
                            COMPONENTE PARA QUE ESTE LOS LEA Y LA BASE LOS ATRAPE-->
                            <form (ngSubmit)="ingresoEmpleados()">
                                <div class="form-floating mb-3">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_CIA" name="COD_CIA" placeholder="name@example.com">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">COD_CIA</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_NEGOCIO" name="COD_NEGOCIO" placeholder="">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">COD_NEGOCIO</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_EMPLEADO" name="COD_EMPLEADO" placeholder="in">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">COD_EMPLEADO</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.PRIMER_NOMBRE" name="PRIMER_NOMBRE" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">PRIMER NOMBRE</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE" name="SEGUNDO_NOMBRE" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">SEGUNDO_NOMBRE</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.PRIMER_APELLIDO" name="PRIMER_APELLIDO" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">PRIMER_APELLIDO</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO" name="SEGUNDO_APELLIDO" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">SEGUNDO_APELLIDO</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.FECHA_NACIMIENTO" name="FECHA_NACIMIENTO" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_AFP" name="COD_AFP" placeholder="Password">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword">COD_AFP</label>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.DUI " name="DUI " placeholder="Password ">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">DUI</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.NIT " name="NIT " placeholder="Password ">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">NIT</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_UNIDAD " name="COD_UNIDAD " placeholder="Password ">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">UNIDAD</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_LABORAL " name="COD_LABORAL " placeholder="Password ">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">Codigo Laboral</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_SUCURSAL " name="COD_SUCURSAL " placeholder="Password ">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">Codigo Sucursal</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.SALARIO_REFERENCIA " name="SALARIO_REFERENCIA " placeholder="Password ">
                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">Salario Referencia</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-floating ">
                                    <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_BANCO " name="COD_BANCO " placeholder="Password ">



                                    <label for="floatingPassword ">Banco</label>
                                </div>






                                <div class="modal-footer ">
                                    <button type="button " class="btn btn-secondary " data-bs-dismiss="modal ">Cerrar</button>
                                    <!--EL BOTÓN SUBMIT HACE QUE TODA LA INFORMACIÓN QUE YO AGREGUE SEA LEÍDA POR LA FUNCION QUE TIENE LA ETIQUETE FORM
                                    Y ESTA INFO SE INTEGRE A LA BASE DE DATOS-->
                                    <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary ">Añadir</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--TABLA QUE ME PERMITE MOSTRAR DATOS-->

        <table class="table mt-3 ">
            <thead class="table-dark ">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col ">Cod_cia</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Primer nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Segundo Nombre</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Primer apellido</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Segundo apellido</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Fecha de nacimiento</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Labor</th>

                    <th scope="col ">AFP</th>


                    <th scope="col ">Banco</th>


                    <th scope="col ">Editar</th>
                    <th scope="col ">Eliminar</th>
                    <th scope="col ">PDF</th>
                    <th scope="col "></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="table-group-divider ">
                <!--POR MEDIO DEL *NGFOR, PUEDO LOGRAR QUE MIS DATOS PUEDAN MOSTRARSE POR MEDIO DE UNA VARIABLE,
                     Y TRAER LOS CAMPOS QUE YO QUIERA MOSTRAR-->
                <tr *ngFor="let p of allAfp ">
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.COD_CIA}}</th>
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.PRIMER_NOMBRE}}</th>
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE}}</th>
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.PRIMER_APELLIDO}}</th>
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO}}</th>
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.FECHA_NACIMIENTO}}</th>
                    <th scope="row ">{{p.DESCRIPCION_1}}</th>


                    <th scope="row ">{{p.DESCRIPCION}}</th>




                    <th scope="row ">{{p.BANCODESC}}</th>

                    <!--MODAL PARA EDITAR DATOS-->
                    <th scope="row "> <button type="button " class="btn btn-primary " data-bs-toggle="modal " data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop ">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-pencil "></i>
                      </button>
                        <!--ES IGUAL QUE EL AGREGAR DATOS, LO UNICO QUE CAMBIA SON UNAS FRASES Y LAS FUNCIONES DENTRO DEL BACKEND-->
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade " id="staticBackdrop " data-bs-backdrop="static " data-bs-keyboard="false " tabindex="-1 " aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel " aria-hidden="true ">
                            <div class="modal-dialog ">
                                <div class="modal-content ">
                                    <div class="modal-header ">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title " id="staticBackdropLabel ">Editar datos</h5>
                                        <button type="button " class="btn-close " data-bs-dismiss="modal " aria-label="Close "></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body ">
                                        <form (ngSubmit)="ActualizarEmpleados() ">
                                            <div class="form-floating mb-3 ">
                                                <input type="email " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_CIA " name="COD_CIA " placeholder="name@example.com ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">COD_CIA</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_NEGOCIO " name="COD_NEGOCIO " placeholder="COD_NEGOCIO ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">COD_NEGOCIO</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_EMPLEADO " name="COD_EMPLEADO " placeholder="COD_EMPLEADO ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">COD_EMPLEADO</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.PRIMER_NOMBRE " name="PRIMER_NOMBRE " placeholder="PRIMER_NOMBRE ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">PRIMER NOMBRE</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.SEGUNDO_NOMBRE " name="SEGUNDO_NOMBRE " placeholder="SEGUNDO_NOMBRE ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">SEGUNDO_NOMBRE</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.PRIMER_APELLIDO " name="PRIMER_APELLIDO " placeholder="PRIMER_APELLIDO ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">PRIMER_APELLIDO</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.SEGUNDO_APELLIDO " name="SEGUNDO_APELLIDO " placeholder="SEGUNDO_APELLIDO ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">SEGUNDO_APELLIDO</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.COD_AFP " name="COD_AFP " placeholder="COD_AFP ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">COD_AFP</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-floating ">
                                                <input type="text " class="form-control " id="floatingInput " [(ngModel)]="modelo.FECHA_NACIMIENTO " name="FECHA_NACIMIENTO " placeholder="Fecha de nacimiento ">
                                                <label for="floatingPassword ">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="modal-footer ">
                                                <button type="button " class="btn btn-secondary " data-bs-dismiss="modal ">Cerrar</button>
                                                <button type="submit " class="btn btn-primary ">Editar</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>


                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </th>
                    <!--MODAL PARA BORRAR DATOS-->
                    <th scope="row ">
                        <!--(click)="EliminarEmpleado(p.COD_CIA) " ES UN EVENTO QUE ME PERMITE BORRAR DATOS SIN LA NECESIDAD DE UN FORMULARIO,
                        EL PROCESO LO TOMA EL COMPONENTE ELIMINAR EMPLEADO DE EMPLEADO.COMPONENT.TS -->
                        <button type="button " (click)="EliminarEmpleado(p.COD_CIA) " class="btn btn-danger ">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can "></i>
                </button></th>

                    <th scope="row ">
                        <button (click)="Generarpdf(p) " type="button " class="btn btn-primary ">
                        <i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf "></i>
                    </button>
                    </th>


                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
```

PD. donde quiero agregar ese drop list es en (COD_AFP, UNIDAD, CODIGO LABORAL Y CODIGO SUCURSAL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu consulta, puedes realizar lo siguiente. Así como tienes métodos que realizan operaciones con PDF, deberás crear otro métdodo en tu **ApiDataService** que traiga la lista de opciones para el dropdown.

**api-data.service.ts**

```
menuDropdown() {
 // Llamada a tu API
}
```

Después, tendrás que crear una variable que recepcione la información de tu API en **EmpleadoComponent**. Si lo que deseas es mostrar la información del menú cuando el componente carga por primera vez, debes llamarlo desde el **ngOnInit**. Te recomiendo revisar el [ciclo de vida de un componente](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) en angular.

**empleado.component.ts**

```
dropdownData: any = [];

ngOnInit() {
 this.loadDropdown();
}

loadDropdown() {
 // Llamas a menuDropdow desde ApiDataService
 this._api.menuDropdow().subscribe((data) => {
  this.dropdownData = data;
 });
}
```

Entonces, desde aquí puedes guiarte del ejemplo que publicaste reemplanzando la variable `items` por `dropdownData` y utilizando la directiva [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor#description) podrás iterar los elementos de la lista.

**Ejemplo de [IgxDropDownComponent](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxdropdowncomponent.html)**

```
<igx-drop-down #dropdown>
    <igx-drop-down-item *ngFor="let menu of dropdownData">
        {{ menu.titulo }}
    </igx-drop-down-item>
</igx-drop-down>
```

**Ejemplo de [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/dropdowns/)**

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li *ngFor="let menu of dropdownData">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{menu.titulo}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Ejemplo común**

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let menu of dropdownData" [value]="menu.id">
   {{menu.titulo}} 
  </option>
</select>
```